# How to handle DCL in Flyway migration scripts?

Tags: java, postgresql, flyway, embedded-database

I have a postgres database that has users and roles already defined.  There are multiple schemas in this database that are all controlled via different projects/flyway scripts.  I am working on adding Flyway integration into a new project where we will use an embedded Postgres instance for testing.

Since none of these users/roles will exist on this instance, they need to be created in a migration script.  However, since these users/roles will already exist in my operational databases, the migrations will fail when they attempt to create the roles.

I already considered writing a function for this, but then the function would have to be included in any project that uses the embedded Postgres and would have to be maintained across multiple code bases.  This seems very sloppy.  Can anyone recommend a way for me to handle these DCL operations using Flyway that will work with the embedded approach as well as my operational databases?

Comment: Doesn't Flyway offer some pre-conditions like Liquibase does? (The migration will only be executed if the pre-condition is true) Or you could use Postgres' `insert ... on conflict do nothing` syntax to make the statements not fail if the rows already exist

Comment: I don't see anything from a cursory google search, or anything obvious in Flyway's documentation about it.  This seems like a pretty important feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous project we use for this approach a set of additional Flyway migration scripts. These scripts we add to the test environment classpath.
We used this for a Flyway version before the feature of Callback and repeatable migrations were added.

Add a callback configuration for your Test environment and you add in the before or after migration phase your user and roles.

Third solution use repeatable migration scripts for your user and roles setup see https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable. Use this scripts in production and test. But in this case your sql must done correct  and repeatable otherwise you will break your production environment.

Comment: It seems like option 2 would be the least-hacky way of doing it.  Since this would be done in a callback, would it fail if the roles already exist?

How do I go about making a callback only for the test environment?  Would I have to have it use a separate path to the migration scripts?

Comment: I thought about Java Callbacks because nwith SQL callbacks it is simular to solution one.
1. Implement your Callback 
2. in test environment you confgure Flyway configuration to use your callback implementation. The configuration depends how your migration works in test phase. Example with Command line see https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate `flyway -callback=your.Callback migrate`

Comment: Aww, I see.  That part has been kind of obfuscated from me in the past because we are using Spring Boot integration so haven't had to do anything fancy with the migrate scripts.